# AngularJS e SEO

Tags: angularjs, seo

Tenho um site feito com AngularJS e PHP.

Todos os conteúdos que são comuns entre páginas apenas são carregados uma única vez, quando o utilizador muda de página apenas o conteúdo da respectiva página é carregado (executando a API em PHP que retorna um JSON) e o respectivo template.

As tags meta "description" e "keywords" mudam conforme a página, mas como não estou recarregando toda a página, isso é um problema.

Como faço?
Ao mudar o conteúdo da página faço um script para mudar o conteúdo das tags?
Isso não será um problema na hora de indexar o site?

Comment: https://prerender.io/ é uma solução opensource para AngularJS que serve HTML pré-renderizado para search engines. Talvez lhe seja interessante.

Answer (score 4):

Se você está usando views e routing no AngularJS, cada página roteada deve ter um controller. Desse modo, você pode usar o seguinte template para executar algo no momento que a view é carregada por completo:

```
/*Estou assumindo que o módulo do controller já está declarado*/
.controller('MeuController', function ($scope) {
  $scope.$on('$viewContentLoaded', function () {
    //Alterar meta tags com jQuery
  });
});
```

Mas o problema maior é que as views só alteram as meta tags se forem carregadas, portanto como os crawlers de Search Engines não executam JavaScript, as tags alteradas não serão capturadas por crawlers; serão necessárias páginas fisicas para isso, infelizmente.

Após ler o texto [deste link](http://moz.com/ugc/can-google-really-access-content-in-javascript-really), percebi que o crawler da Google consegue ler e executar javascript, porém, esse javascript DEVE estar na mesma página. Em suma, o link fez os seguintes testes:

1. Uso de `document.write()` dentro de `<script></script>` num único arquivo HTML = Crawler leu.
2. Uso de `document.write()` num arquivo `.js` externo = Crawler não leu.
3. Uso de `innerHTML` dentro de `<script></script>` num único arquivo HTML = Crawler leu.
4. Uso de `innerHTML` num arquivo `.js` externo = Crawler não leu.
5. Uso de abas com jQuery = Crawler leu, e associou todo conteúdo a apenas uma página.
6. Uso de abas com AJAX = Crawler leu, mas associou cada aba a uma página própria.

No geral, a melhor ideia é colocar nas tags `<meta>` o que você quer que seja indexado, mesmo que parte do que está nas tags esteja nas views, e não na página inicial em si.

Comment: Penso já conseguem ler o javascript, pelo menos o Google.

Comment: @Filipe Complementei a resposta.